# free reporting tool for tfs express 2012

Tags: tfs

We are using TFS 2012 express edition, is there any free reporting tool available, which will show a burndown chart and my company also like to get reports on the numbers bugs created and so on .. or something similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a query and save it after that open it with excel and insert graph after that save the report for future needs and when you open it go to team and click refresh to refresh it's data

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use report Builder. It can make both SSRS and EXEL reports

http://tech.lds.org/wiki/LDS_.NET_Stack/TFS_Reports_using_SSRS

Answer (score 0):

I work with the Urban Turtle Team. We offer a new add-on for TFS: the Agile Dashboard. It provides you with useful reports (burndown charts, budget graphs, etc.) to follow your project.

I understand that you wanted a free tool, but its price is fairly low for unlimited users.

Check it out: [urbanturtle.com/tfs-agile-dashboard](http://urbanturtle.com/tfs-agile-dashboard)

Comment: You should have a small subset of the tools that works with TFS Express for free. Good way to get individuals familiar with your product.